# Firebase/Swift update table view value on delete?

Tags: arrays, swift, firebase, tableview, firebase-realtime-database

I was just wondering how I would update my display data in Swift from firebase through .observeEventType - and an array of dictionaries that I have. I have a table view, with a delete button function. However, I only get to delete the value from firebase, not the array of dictionaries. I have the observeEventType in my viewDidLoad, getting my data like this:

```
var dict = [String:String]()
dict["data"] = snapshot.value!["data"] as? String
array.append(dict)
```

However, in the numberOfRowsInSection I have array.count, and I get an error that the count is wrong. How would I solve this problem? Deleting the value from the array of dictionaries, do the whole data fethcing all over and display the new data, or what do I do?

Btw: When the app crashes, and I build it again - the deleted value is gone, and the data shows properly - however, I just want the delete part to run smooth.

Thanks in advance.

Whole code:

```
func LoadValues() {


        var curID = FIRAuth.auth()?.currentUser?.uid

        ref.child("Users").child(curID!).child("Prices").observeEventType(.Value) { (snapshot:FIRDataSnapshot) in


            if let PermPrice = snapshot.value!["PermanentPrice"] as? Int {
                self.dict2["PermanentPrice"] = String(PermPrice)
            }

            if let Price24 = snapshot.value!["24hours"] as? Int {
                self.dict2["24hours"] = String(Price24)
            }

            if let Price12 = snapshot.value!["12hours"] as? Int {
                self.dict2["12hours"] = String(Price12)
            }

            if let Price6 = snapshot.value!["6hours"] as? Int {
                self.dict2["6hours"] = String(Price6)
            }

            if let Price2 = snapshot.value!["2hours"] as? Int {
                self.dict2["2hours"] = String(Price2)
            }

            self.allTiers.append(self.dict2)

        }

    }
```

The code above is a price tier system, allowing the user to choose between 5 different price tiers. That displays in the table view.

And this is to display in the tableview:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        if indexPath.row == 0 {

            let cell1 = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("firstCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! TierCell1

            cell1.deleteButton1.tag = 0

            cell1.deleteButton1.addTarget(self, action: "DeleteTier:", forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)
            //let cell1 = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("firstCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! TierCell1

            //set the data here

            if allTiers[0]["PermanentPrice"] != nil {
                cell1.price1.text = "$" + String(allTiers[0]["PermanentPrice"]!)
                cell1.text1.text = "Permanent"
                PermTextTier = true
            } else if allTiers[0]["24hours"] != nil {
                cell1.price1.text = "$" + String(allTiers[0]["24hours"]!)
                cell1.text1.text = "24 hours"
                TextTier24 = true
            } else if allTiers[0]["12hours"] != nil {
                cell1.price1.text = "$" + String(allTiers[0]["12hours"]!)
                cell1.text1.text = "12 hours"
                TextTier12 = true
            } else if allTiers[0]["6hours"] != nil {
                cell1.price1.text = "$" + String(allTiers[0]["6hours"]!)
                cell1.text1.text = "6 hours"
                TextTier6 = true
            } else if allTiers[0]["2hours"] != nil {
                cell1.price1.text = "$" + String(allTiers[0]["2hours"]!)
                cell1.text1.text = "2 hours"
                TextTier2 = true
            }

            //cell1.text1.text = String(allTiers[0]["PermanentPrice"]!)

            return cell1
        }
        if indexPath.row == 1 {
            //let cell2: TierCell2 = TierCell2(style: UITableViewCellStyle.Default, reuseIdentifier: "secondCell") as! TierCell2
            //set the data here


            let cell2 = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("secondCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! TierCell2


            cell2.deleteButton2.tag = 1

            cell2.deleteButton2.addTarget(self, action: "DeleteTier:", forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)


            if allTiers[0]["24hours"] != nil && TextTier24 == false {
                cell2.price2.text = "$" + String(allTiers[0]["24hours"]!)
                cell2.text2.text = "24 hours"
                TextTier24 = true
            } else if allTiers[0]["12hours"] != nil && TextTier12 == false {
                cell2.price2.text = "$" + String(allTiers[0]["12hours"]!)
                cell2.text2.text = "12 hours"
                TextTier12 = true
            } else if allTiers[0]["6hours"] != nil && TextTier6 == false {
                cell2.price2.text = "$" + String(allTiers[0]["6hours"]!)
                cell2.text2.text = "6 hours"
                TextTier6 = true
            } else if allTiers[0]["2hours"] != nil && TextTier2 == false {
                cell2.price2.text = "$" + String(allTiers[0]["2hours"]!)
                cell2.text2.text = "2 hours"
                TextTier2 = true
            }



            return cell2
        }
        if indexPath.row == 2 {
            //let cell2: TierCell2 = TierCell2(style: UITableViewCellStyle.Default, reuseIdentifier: "secondCell") as! TierCell2
            //set the data here

            let cell3 = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("thirdCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! TierCell3

            cell3.deleteButton3.tag = 2

            cell3.deleteButton3.addTarget(self, action: "DeleteTier:", forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)

            if allTiers[0]["12hours"] != nil && TextTier12 == false {
                cell3.price3.text = "$" + String(allTiers[0]["12hours"]!)
                cell3.text3.text = "12 hours"
                TextTier12 = true
            } else if allTiers[0]["6hours"] != nil && TextTier6 == false {
                cell3.price3.text = "$" + String(allTiers[0]["6hours"]!)
                cell3.text3.text = "6 hours"
                TextTier6 = true
            } else if allTiers[0]["2hours"] != nil && TextTier2 == false {
                cell3.price3.text = "$" + String(allTiers[0]["2hours"]!)
                cell3.text3.text = "2 hours"
                TextTier2 = true
            }


            return cell3
        }
        if indexPath.row == 3 {
            //let cell2: TierCell2 = TierCell2(style: UITableViewCellStyle.Default, reuseIdentifier: "secondCell") as! TierCell2
            //set the data here
            let cell4 = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("fourthCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! TierCell4

            cell4.deleteButton4.tag = 3

            cell4.deleteButton4.addTarget(self, action: "DeleteTier:", forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)

            if allTiers[0]["6hours"] != nil && TextTier6 == false {
                cell4.price4.text = "$" + String(allTiers[0]["6hours"]!)
                cell4.text4.text = "6 hours"
                TextTier6 = true
            } else if allTiers[0]["2hours"] != nil && TextTier2 == false {
                cell4.price4.text = "$" + String(allTiers[0]["2hours"]!)
                cell4.text4.text = "2 hours"
                TextTier2 = true
            }

            return cell4
        }
        if indexPath.row == 4 {
            //let cell2: TierCell2 = TierCell2(style: UITableViewCellStyle.Default, reuseIdentifier: "secondCell") as! TierCell2
            //set the data here
            let cell5 = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("fifthCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! TierCell5

            cell5.deleteButton5.tag = 4

            cell5.deleteButton5.addTarget(self, action: "DeleteTier:", forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)

            if allTiers[0]["2hours"] != nil && TextTier2 == false {
                cell5.price5.text = "$" + String(allTiers[0]["2hours"]!)
                cell5.text5.text = "2 hours"
                TextTier2 = true
            }


            return cell5
        } else {
            let cell: UITableViewCell = UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.Default, reuseIdentifier: "none")


            return cell
        }



    }
```

This code looks rather messy, but I just want to display The higest price tier on top, at any time. This does not update when I remove a value.

Comment: can you add the firebase call that retrieve the data to the tableview?

Comment: @adolfosrs I believe the problem lies in the cellForRowAtIndexPath, but I can't think of another way of doing it..

Comment: Do you happen to see a solution here, @adolfosrs?

Comment: Still not figuring it out..

Answer (score 0):

There is some design problems with your code and I would start searching for a better approach on how to handle the TableView in your case. So, keep it in mind.

With your current TableView code and if I didnt miss anything, to achieve what you are looking for thats how you should be retrieveing your data:

```
func LoadValues() {
    var curID = FIRAuth.auth()?.currentUser?.uid
    ref.child("Users").child(curID!).child("Prices").observeEventType(.Value, withBlock: { snapshot in
        if let PermPrice = snapshot.value!["PermanentPrice"] as? Int {
            self.dict2["PermanentPrice"] = String(PermPrice)
        }
        if let Price24 = snapshot.value!["24hours"] as? Int {
            self.dict2["24hours"] = String(Price24)
        }
        if let Price12 = snapshot.value!["12hours"] as? Int {
            self.dict2["12hours"] = String(Price12)
        }
        if let Price6 = snapshot.value!["6hours"] as? Int {
            self.dict2["6hours"] = String(Price6)
        }
        if let Price2 = snapshot.value!["2hours"] as? Int {
            self.dict2["2hours"] = String(Price2)
        }
        self.allTiers.removeAll()
        self.allTiers.append(self.dict2)
    }
}
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to solve my problem. After I delete the row, the table view updates with wrong values.

Comment: @askaale this is pretty much how i can help u. You might be messing with your data in somewhere else.